# How to implement flipper over in memory game?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-animation

I am working on a simple memory game where I fetch 9 images from server and I am showing them in a 3X3 grid view. Once the images are loaded, user can see images for 15 seconds. After 15 seconds all images should be flipped over. Now after 15 seconds I am showing one image view below grid view. In this image view I am showing one randomly picked image from the above 9 images. Now user needs to select correct position of the image in grid view. If user select correct position in grid view then I need to flipped back image with the correct image. Game will end when user flipped back all images.

I have fetched images and shown it in grid view but i don't know how to Flipped over and flipped back images. **I checked flip animation in android but it's for rotating image.** In my case image should not be visible when it's flipped over and it should be visible when it flipped back. How to implement flipped over and flipped back in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to introduce you to the `Camera` class. No, not the hardware camera.

[Camera | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html)

This is the `graphics` `Camera`.  Whereas the standard scale, rotate, and translate animations all work in the x-y plane only, `Camera` introduces a z-axis which gives *perspective* on an image and allows you to transform on three dimensions instead of two.

You will be most interested in the `rotateY()` method.  This is the method that will help you create an animation of a card or tile being flipped over.

Here's how I used the `Camera` class for a tile flip:

```
    private Matrix mMatrix;

    private Camera mCamera;

    // val is animation value between -1.0 and 1.0
    private void updateImageMatrix(float val) {

        // turn the animation value into an angle from 
        // 0 to -90, then +90 to 0 degrees
        float degrees = 90.0F * (Math.signum(val) - val);

        mCamera.save();               // save initial state
        mCamera.rotateY(degrees);     // this does the flip
        mCamera.getMatrix(mMatrix);   // write the transform into the matrix
        mCamera.restore();            // now we can reuse the Camera without re-constructing

        float centerX = imageWidth / 2.0F;
        float centerY = imageHeight / 2.0F;

        // Y-axis is at the left edge, so to get rotation
        // around the center, we have to move the image over
        // first, then move it back after we rotate
        mRotateMatrix.preTranslate(- centerX, - centerY);
        mRotateMatrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
        // this could probably be eliminated by initializing mCamera with
        // mCamera.setLocation(centerX, centerY, mCamera.getLocationZ())

        // the image probably isn't exactly the same size as the
        // view, so we have to handle scaling the image to the view
        mRotateMatrix.preScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    }
```

Now that you have a matrix to do the transform, you can use this in a number of ways:

1. You can have an `ImageView` with this matrix set as the image matrix
2. You can have a custom `View` that overrides `onDraw` and call `canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mMatrix, null)`
3. You can have a custom `Animation` class that overrides `applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)` and returns an updated `Transformation` based on the matrix

Also, with a flip, you will want to animate the first image from 0 to -90 degrees, then hide that image, and show the second image while animating the rest of the way from 90 to 0 degrees.

One last thing.  You have a 3x3 grid. To get a realistic 3-D flipping effect, you will want to experiment with `mCamera.setLocation()` using differing values of x and y depending on the tile so that the top tiles will look like you are viewing the flip from underneath, the bottom tiles will look like you are viewing the flip from overhead, etc.